# SQL Query to return rows with no matches in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a users country table where I hold a list of users country's- a user can have many addresses and therefore many country's

it is joined to the user table via an address table

if I do a select distinct CountryId from UserCountry Data returned is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
etc
```

If I run the following query I get a User returned

```
select * from User u join Address a
on u.AddressId = a.Id
where a.CountryId = 1
```

If I then run

```
select * from User u join Address a
on u.AddressId = a.Id
where a.CountryId = 2
```

I get no data returned which is fine.  What I need to to do is pass in a list of all the distinct Country Ids and produce a output of which set return a User Object and which set don't return a User object

Comment: search for outer joins. I think that is what you need. Then just filter if a certain attribute in the user entity is NULL or not.

Comment: how can a user have many addresses if addressid is on the user table?

Comment: @JamieD77 - sorry that was a typo - will edit to remove that

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL server?

Comment: @Sculper SQL server.  Tags updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query:

```
SELECT CountryId, COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) AS usersPerCountry 
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT CountryId 
   FROM UserCountry) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT a.CountryId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM User u 
   INNER JOIN Address a ON u.AddressId = a.Id
   GROUP BY a.CountryId
) AS t2 ON t1.CountryId = t2.CountryId
ORDER BY COALESCE(t2.cnt, 0) DESC
```

will give you the number of users associated with each country. If a country is not related to any users at all then `0` is returned.

**Explanation:**

The above query makes use of two derived tables, `t1` and `t2`:

- The first derived table of the query, `t1`, contains a list of all distinct `CountryId` values contained in `UserCountry`.
- The second derived table, `t2`, returns the number of users per `CountryId`. Ids with no users are not returned by this sub-query.

Performing a `LEFT JOIN` between `t1` and `t2` with `t1` as the first table returns *all* values of `t1`, i.e. *all* `CountryId` values contained in `UserCountry`. If there is no match in `t2`, then `t2.cnt` is `NULL`. `COALESCE` used in the `SELECT` clause converts this `NULL` value into a `0`.

Comment: Just what I needed - cheers - for my own understanding could you add a bit of extra info just explaining how the query is working

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all items in User and Address that do not have a Country entry. Is this what you are looking for?

```
SELECT *
FROM User U
JOIN Address a
ON a.Id = u.AddressId
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM UserCountry uc
   WHERE uc.CountryId = a.CountryId
);
```

For the list of `Country` items that do not have a User, you can alternate the statements and find where the `CountryId` `NOT EXISTS` in the `User` and `Address` tables

Comment: pretty sure he wants everything from usercountry.. where the country id is not in the address table

Comment: This query isn't producing any output.